# changing url, and locale on the fly with laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

My code in laravel to handle multiple language is:

```
$languages = array('it-IT','en-GB','fr-FR');
    $lingua = Request::segment(1);
    if(in_array($lingua, $languages)){
        \App::setLocale($lingua);
    }else{
        $lingua = 'it-IT';
    }


Route::group(array('prefix' => $lingua), function()
{

    Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'ItemController@menu'));
    Route::get('/{idcampo}','ItemController@show');
});
```

How can i:

1)Make the page start always with it-IT as default. (i need it because I use $lingua to fetch from a database) so i can't have that null. Should I use a redirect::to / to /it-IT?

2) change url and language(app:locale) on he fly with a link in the upper section of every pages. withouth returning to the home.

3) to link pages I learn to use: 
`URL::route('home')` 
but how to do it when the link change with the entry of a database (for example my link is `{{ URL::to($lingua. '/'.  $campo[1].'/') }}`) I need to use 
`URL::action('ItemController@show', ($lingua. '/'.  $campo[1].'/'))`

EDIT:

OK at the top of my pages there is a link to change language on the fly.

```
<a href="{{URL::action('LanguageController@select', 'it-IT')}}"> Italian </a> //
<a href="{{URL::action('LanguageController@select', 'en-GB')}}"> English </a> // 
<a href="{{URL::action('LanguageController@select', 'fr-FR')}}"> French </a>
```

I create a controller clled LanguageController

```
<?php

class LanguageController extends BaseController {

    public function select($lingua)

    {
         // Store the current language in the session
    Session::put('lingua', $lingua);

    return Redirect::back(); // redirect to the same page, nothing changes, just the language                           

    }
}
```

I create a route:

```
  Route::get('lingua/{lingua}', 'LanguageController@select');
    Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'ItemController@menu'));
    Route::get('/mondo/','ItemController@mondo');
    Route::get('/{idcampo}','ItemController@show');
```

I have my ItemController@menu

```
public function menu()

{   $linguadefault='it-IT';
    $lingua = Session::get('lingua',$linguadefault);
    $data = DB::table('campo')->lists('id');
    return View::make('index')->with('campo',$data)->with('lingua',$lingua);


}
```

1) I don't understand why i need to route at lingua/{lingua} if i never route there but i use a url:action to a controller directly.

2) now i need to add

```
$linguadefault='it-IT';
        $lingua = Session::get('lingua',$linguadefault);
```

at the beginning of every function to have a lingua variable in my page right?

3) now my language seems stucked to french and i can't change it anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use the language in the URL all the time, you can just switch languages when you need and persist it:

1) Use Session to persist the language chosen:

```
// Set the default language to the current user language
// If user is not logged, defaults to Italian
$linguaDefault = Auth::check()
                 ? Auth::user()->lingua
                 : 'it-IT';

/// If not stored in Session, current language will be the default one
\App::setLocale(Session::get('lingua', $linguaDefault));
```

To have the language always set in your application, **you can put this code in your file**

```
app/start/global.php
```

And you don't need to add this anywhere else. So it will use it in this order:

```
a) Language stored in Session (selected online)
b) Language user has in database
c) Italian
```

2) To change the language you create a route:

```
Route::get('lingua/{lang}', 'LanguageController@select');
```

Your links

```
URL::action('LanguageController@select', 'it-IT')
URL::action('LanguageController@select', 'en-GB')
URL::action('LanguageController@select', 'fr-FR');
```

And in your controller you just have to do:

```
public function select($lang)
{
    // Store the current language in the session
    Session::put('lingua', $lang);

    return Redirect::back(); // redirect to the same page, nothing changes, just the language
}
```

3) This way you don't need your language in all your URLs, you don't have to deal with it in all your routes. If your user changes the language in database, you just:

```
$user->save();
Session::put('lingua', $user->lingua);
return Redirect::route('home'); // or anything else
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but my website has no user, i mean, it just have to fetch description from database according to the current language.
I thought to put language in url because i saw a lot of website has url/nl or url/en or url/it in their webpages

Comment: Yeah, but I like my urls clean... And you don't need it there to make languages work fine, give it a shot.

Comment: I am trying to use this, but i am a little confused on session. I mean, my language doesn't change now

Comment: Could you pastebin your code so I can try to help you?

Comment: Seems that is stucked on french

Comment: the link works: when i see source
http://localhost/Project/public/lingua/it-IT

I shouldn't put something like App:setLocale? somewhere to change locale

Comment: About your 2), put the code in your app/start/global.php.

Comment: Yeah i check with dd($lingua) and language is changing, maybe i just need to add App:setLocale($lingua) somewhere to change locale

Comment: About 1), the route lingua/{lingua} is just for your user to select the language, it will do nothing else.

Comment: Putting those 2 lines in your `app/start/global.php` should make it work every time. Also, to debug you can do this: http://laravel.io/bin/4l6L

Comment: Thank you so much! now i don't have to get crazy with language in the url and your solution is cleaner i must admit it.

BTW, putting things in app/start/global.php i have a $lingua variable always available everywhere?

Comment: Seems like that to use $lingua variable in the pages i need to put
$linguadefault='it-IT';
$lingua = Session::get('lingua',$linguadefault); at the beginning of each controller function is it ok right?

Comment: Added two more lines here, to show how to get the language everywhere: http://laravel.io/bin/9K6W

Comment: You don't need the default anymore in your controller, it's being set in your global.php.

Comment: Why do you need this in your controllers? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to use the language $lingua in the query to take the right decription of the item.